Render DOCX file in React
I am trying to render a document present in S3 location using a presign url. I am using react-doc-viewer library to do it. However I am getting CORS error in browser console.
I have configured my S3 bucket to Allow CORS and it is as below.
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "http://localhost:3000"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}

]
Here is My React Component.
import React from "react";
import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from "react-doc-viewer";

interface SpecterDocViewerProps {
  url: string;
}

const SpecterDocViewer: React.FC<SpecterDocViewerProps> = ({ url }) => {
  const documents = [{ uri: url }];

  return (
    <DocViewer
      documents={documents}
      pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
      config={{
        header: {
          disableHeader: false,
          disableFileName: false,
          retainURLParams: false,
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default SpecterDocViewer;


Error

Access to fetch at
'https://my-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my_file.docx?AWS
Generated Code' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked
by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set
the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS
disabled.

